# Graph Theory Depth First Search

Tags: algorithm, graph, traversal, depth-first-search

While implementing DFS traversal using stacks, do we need to push the element into the stack if it's already inside the stack but not visited?

Comment: Please include some code to show
[what you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: No. If a node is already on the stack, you don't have to push it back in again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we need to push the element into the stack if it's already inside
>   the stack but not visited?

The answer is **no**, because it's one way to go into loops..

If you are traversing a Graph using Depth-First Search, you are likely to get caught in loops..

The best way to avoid that problem is using a Taboo List, which keeps the IDs of all visited nodes..

```
stack.push(init);

while (!stack.empty())
{
    current = stack.pop();
    taboo.add(current.id);

    if (isGoal(current))
    {
        break;
    }

    for (Node neighbor : getNeighbors(current))
    {
        if (!taboo.contains(neighbor.id))
        {
            stack.push(neighbor);
        }
    }

}
```